# Import MySQL tables recovered into new MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, import

I have the data files of an old MySQL database (.frm, .MID, .MYI), taken from a server hard disk.
No way to be sure about MySQL version: I have no access to the server, I only know the server was a linux machine, built in 2009 or 2010, and then left alone without maintenance.

I downloaded and installed the last MySQL .MSI, but I'm totally new to MySQ.

The first step I need is importing my data into a new MySQL database, and then with a Delphi program I plan to move the data into a SQL Server DB.

How can i import these data tables?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can stop mysql server, create some folder like old_data in mysql data directory, put all your .frm, .MID, .MYI files there and start mysql. After doing so you should be able to see old_data database in results of the `SHOW DATABASES` command.

Comment: How can I find the MySQL data directory on a XP SP3 computer?
I'm trying using MySQL WorkBench 5.2: it builds a .MWB file, I can select a directory, i put there the files, but the DB contains nothing.

Comment: solved with xampp ... it can see the old MySQL files, and export them in a SQL script (a very stupid SQL script, but a SQL script)